# SQL statements in javaScript AJAX request

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ajax

I've been programming only in JavaScript and now I'd like to work with some databases and learn SQL. I'm wondering if it is common and safe attitude, to send SQL statements in the AJAX requests, for example like this:

```
xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     //something
  }
};
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM Customers'; //creating SQL statements in JS like this
xhttp.open("GET", "getFromDatabase.php?q="+sql, true);
xhttp.send();

//PHP:
$result = mysqli_query($con,$q);
echo $result;
```

instead of keeping and generating all necessary SQL statements inside the php file indicated in AJAX open() like this:

```
xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     //something
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "getFromDatabase.php?q=getCustomers", true);
xhttp.send();

//PHP:
if ($q==="getCustomers") {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Customers";  //here are ALL SQL statements
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo $result;
}
```

All the tutorials and samples on the Internet I've read up prefer the second attitube, but for me - who do not know PHP and don't want to learn at this time - the first (JS) attitude would be easier, just for learning and testing how to handle databases. Then I could create a simple php file just for returning JSON with some data and all other stuff do in JavaScript.

Comment: And that is how your whole database is stolen/deleted... do not do this... They need to be in the php.... if not anyone can run a SQL request.

Comment: Either stolen or someone opens the console and does the request with the statement `DROP TABLE Customers`

Comment: Given the tools that the user has access, malicious people will be able to modify and exploit this type of code, and you could get your data leaked.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "NO!". Please do not do that.  That opens your database up for SQL injection attacks and other security unfriendly things.

If you want to learn how to use SQL, write a RESTful service in PHP, Node.js, Python, or another easily to learn language and run SQL in he backend.

Never pass strings from a UI directly into a database without parameterizing them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I will suggest you to use flags ... send different flags in ajax request for executing different queries in php ... the php script will get the flag and decide which query to run ...

Comment: Much better than the OP's idea, still a pain to maintain once you have 200 or 300 queries running in production.